# Finding marginal pdf from joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)~=~\begin{cases}6xy & 0\le x \le 1 ~,~ 0\le y\le \sqrt{x} \\[1ex] 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Find $F_Y{(y)}$

Now, at first I thought this was a straightforward question but the answer given was different from mine, particularly the bounds of the integral.

The solution was given by 
$$f_Y(y)~=~\int_{y^2}^{1}6xy ~\mathrm dx~=~3y(1-y^4)$$

Why do they use from the bound from $y^2 \to 1$? My bound was  $0\to 1$ given by $0 \le x \le 1$

Comment: And what did you do with the condition $0\le y\le\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @Did used it to calculate marginal pdf of x, $f_X{(x)}$

Comment: Draw a picture of the region where the joint density "lives."  That picture will give you the bounds when we "integrate out" $x$.

Comment: the image is shown @ http://imgur.com/MrFYKka

Comment: @misheekoh: We are at height $y$, where $0\lt y\lt 1$, and are "adding up" (integrating) the joint density at that height. We first endter the blue (?) region where $y=\sqrt{x}$, that is, where $x=y^2$. We leave it where $x=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My bound was $0→1$ given by $0≤x≤1$

The support is *both* $0\leq x \leq 1$ *and* $0\leq y\leq\sqrt{x} $

So, for a specific value of $y$ where can $x$ lie?   That would be $~y^2\leq x \leq 1~$, giving the bounds of the integral.   Also note that the support for the margin of $y$ is then $0\leq y\leq 1$.

$$f_Y(y) = \int_{y^2}^1 6xy\operatorname d x~~\mathbf 1_{0\leq y\leq 1}$$